# Server Pinging but not accessible through HTTP and SSH

Tags: ubuntu, aws

So I have an AWS Machine running Ubuntu 18.04. It was running fine till now but now it's not connecting via HTTP or SSH.

If I ping the IP, I get a response..

Here's the SSH log.

```
MacBook-Pro-2:downloads user$ ssh -v ubuntu@3.7.***.**
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 3.7.***.** [3.7.***.**] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
```

Comment: I wouldn't access an AWS host by it's IP, have you tried symbolic name ? like `ec2-1-2-3-4.region.compute.amazonaws.com` (with proper value as given by EC2's interface of course).

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. Doesn't load.